# Github Pages: This branch is even with gh-pages

Tags: git, github, git-branch, github-pages

I wanted to host a little web app that I wrote on github.io. So I've created a new orphan branch and called it gh-pages (it's essentially the same as my master branch). I made all the contributions and pushed it on Github. It works perfectly just as I have expected it.

The only thing that's weird is, that when I enter the gh-pages branch on Github it shows me a message that says: This branch is even with gh-pages. Did i made some misconseption here or is it normal and can't be changed?

You can see that branch and the message here: [My Github Repository with the error](https://github.com/FrankenApps/TicTacToe/tree/gh-pages) (my site that showed the error, before I fixed it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've found a ressource finally and it says, that if your project hosted on Github is a website, instead of the master branch, you should simply call your main branch gh-pages. I think this is the most simple and logic way to do it and the message "This branch is even with gh-pages" is gone now, while everything is still working perfectly. Doing it this way helps me to push changes, too, because I can simply commit them to gh-pages instead of thinking about adding a change to both the master and my gh-pages branch.

Answer (score 1):

I see the gh-pages and master branch have 3 common(initial) commits.
[image]

So, the gh-pages branch is not an orphan branch.

I think, this is the reason why github.com is showing "This branch is even with gh-pages".

Comment: Orphan branch:

The first commit made on this new branch(orphan) will have no parents and it will be the root of a new history totally disconnected from all the other branches and commits.

Comment: Ah so what is the problem when it's not an orphan branch, and how can I make it one again?

Comment: 1. Clone the repo: `git clone github.com/user/repository.git`

2. cd repository

3. Create gh-pages orphan branch: `git checkout --orphan gh-pages`

4.  Remove all the files: `git rm -rf .`